# Only the last element is shown in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a sample database in Firebase that is meant to display some facts. Currently, I want the textview to display all the five sample facts 1,2,3,4,5..but it shows only the last one. Where should I modify on my code?

Java sample:

```
fact = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Facts");

        fact.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Fact factdata = postSnapshot.getValue(Fact.class);

                    factViewBox.setText(factdata.getFactDetail());


                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

And the json:

```
"Facts":{
    "01":{
   "factDetail":"1" 
   }
,

"02":{
   "factDetail":"2" 
}
,
"03":{
   "factDetail":"3" 
}
,
"04":{
   "factDetail":"4" 
}
,
"05":{
   "factDetail":"5" 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code doing is just replacing the current text in the TextView with the `factdata.getFactDetail()`.

For example you have 3 elements 1, 2, and 3. Then you want to display the element inside the TextView. With your code, this is what happen

First iteration:

```
element = elements[0];        // element = 1
factViewBox.setText(element); // TextView text is "1"
```

Second iteration:

```
element = elements[1];        // element = 2
factViewBox.setText(element); // TextView text is "2"
```

Third iteration:

```
element = elements[2];        // element = 3
factViewBox.setText(element); // TextView text is "3"
```

Therefore, your TextView only displaying the last element/fact detail

Comment: I've understood this now thanks. Could you please have any input on the follow up question I've made above?

Comment: So, you are thinking to use a button as navigation between fact and display the fact to the same `TextView`? Yes, that is possible. But you need to store all your fact to an array first. In the button `onClick`, just use the same method `setText` to set the `TextView` text with the current fact you want to display. So you need an `array` and an `index` variable. Be careful with the classic `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){    
    Fact factdata = postSnapshot.getValue(Fact.class); 
    if(factViewBox.getText().length() > 0 ){
         factViewBox.setText(factViewBox.getText() + "\n" + factdata.getFactDetail());
    }else{
         factViewBox.setText(factdata.getFactDetail());
    }
 }
```

you need to change in the for loop

Comment: Wow that worked well! One last thing if you don't mind... Is there a way to display those facts one by one on the textview? I was thinking of using a button to show the next fact each time it's clicked..

Comment: The thing is I have not a clue how to do it. If you could demonstrate with a sample code I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: check this link out https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Checked it out, only that it does not address how to display the items one by one either by swiping the screen left or right, or by clicking a next or a previous button. I really appreciate the help BTW.

Comment: I mean, its not clear how it addresses the click button to show next/prev item :(