# Firebase RecyclerView OnDataChanged only last element is Shown

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am developing android chat app following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voIFz8aE9eE) i am retriving the whole list of friends Then on the basis of their user id i retrive the user's data from the user data that is user name, user image and user status the databases are shown below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3opoN.png]

and

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yC2K.png]

So now what is the main problem, the main problem is by the following code:

```
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(FriendsFragment.friendsViewHolder holder, int position, Friends model) {

            final String list_User_id=getRef(position).getKey();

            mUserdatabase.child(list_User_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        UserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        friendsViewHolder.setName(UserName);
                        UserStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                        friendsViewHolder.setStatus(UserStatus);
                        thumb_img = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_img").getValue().toString();
                        friendsViewHolder.setThumbnail(thumb_img,getActivity());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent prfile_Intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileActivity.class);
                    prfile_Intent.putExtra("User_id",list_User_id);
                    startActivity(prfile_Intent);

                }
            });
```

it give me a recyclerView in result
in which only last element is show as shown in figure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xteUF.png]

i google it and also searching on Stackover flow but cannot find the solution from last 3 days.
A simillar is Question is asked but i cannot solve my problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280717/only-the-last-element-is-shown-in-firebase-database) 
please help and donot down vote my question 
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

`addValueEventListener` in the `onBindViewHolder` method is the very bad idea. You can make a list of user in your Fragment and pass that list into Adapter.

Comment: But i am using Firebase RecyclerView so how i can pass my own list to it

Comment: Make the query to directly get User's list in RecyclerView so in PopulateViewHolder you can set data directly

Comment: Thanks you for your interest Now fire base updated the ui so PopulateViewHolder is not avilable

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `onBindViewHolder()` method is called as many times as the number of items that are coming from your database. So in this case, everything is inside this method is also triggered. This means that you are attaching a listener on every `onBindViewHolder()` method call. There is no need for doing that. You can simply get the user name and all the other properties directly from the `model` object which is passed as an argument to this method like this:

```
String UserName = model.getUserName();
String UserStatus = model.getUserStatus();
//And so on for the other properties.
```

Comment: I understand the execution of onBindViewHolder() that is iterating but in model class that is friend class i want to store only User id and on the basis of User is i get the data of that User from User node

Comment: As you suggested above for that solution i will need to put name,status,image to save in Friend node which is already available in user so there will repeation of data

Comment: In this case you should iterate twice, once to get the user if from the friend node and second to actually get the data. But don't do this inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method because you'll end up having a single item in your RecyclerView. And repetition is not a bad thing when is comes to Firebase. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Thank you for help me i will try your suggestion but how i don't know yat